# Jekyll на gulp отказывается работать в win32

Tags: gulp, jekyll

Я работал на стационарном компе с 64-битной системой - всё было в порядке.
Решил работать на планшете с 32-х битной системой.
Перенес все файлы проекта (без node_modules), установил `node.js`, запустил `npm i`, по идее, все модули и зависимости должны установиться сами собой. Перед этим, конечно, глобально установил `gulp-cli`.
sass, jade, js компилируются без проблем, значит, можно считать, gulp и зависимости установились.
Проблема в том, что я не знаю, почему ошибка.
В Интернете нашел решение через добавление `exec` заместо `spawn` к возвращаемому childprocess (у меня он просто как child подключен в галпфайле). Добавил - это решило одну проблему, но появилась другая ошибка (текущая в вопросе).
Также у некоторых людей такая же ошибка (как у меня в впоросе) появляется из-за того, что они забыли исключить из компиляции `jekyll` папку `node_modules`. Но я исключил её в файле `_config.yml`:

```
exclude: ["node_modules", "gulpfile.js", "package.json"]
```

И не понятно, в чем проблема.
Вот мой таск `[jekyll]`, в котором возникает ошибка (конкретно - в последней строчке):

```
var messages = {jekyllBuild: '<span style="color: grey">Running:</span> $ jekyll build'};
gulp.task('jekyll-build', function (done) {
    browserSync.notify(messages.jekyllBuild);
    var pl = process.platform === "win32" ? "jekyll.bat" : "jekyll";
    return child.exec(pl, ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'}).on('close', done);
});
```

А вот сама ошибка:

```
[14:55:51] Using gulpfile C:\Web\vostoksisters\gulpfile.js
[14:55:51] Starting 'sync group0:0'...
[14:55:51] Starting 'jade'...
[14:55:51] Finished 'jade' after 44 ms
[14:55:51] Starting 'sass'...
[14:55:51] Starting 'js'...
[14:55:51] Finished 'js' after 6.95 ms
[14:55:53] Finished 'sass' after 2.06 s
[14:55:53] Finished 'sync group0:0' after 2.12 s
[14:55:53] Starting 'sync group0:1'...
[14:55:53] Starting 'jekyll-build'...
[14:55:53] 'jekyll-build' errored after 32 ms
[14:55:53] Error: 1
    at formatError (C:\Users\reall\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\reall\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Gulp.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (C:\Web\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
    at C:\Web\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
    at finish (C:\Web\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at ChildProcess.cb (C:\Web\vostoksisters\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
    at emitTwo (events.js:111:20)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
```

И мой package.json:

```
{
  "name": "template_site",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "-",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "none",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-babili": "0.0.12",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.2.0",
    "babili": "0.0.12",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.4.5",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-jade": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sync": "^0.1.4",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^5.2.1",
    "jekyll": "^3.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-json-minify": "^1.0.7"
  }
}
```

Ну и если совсем хочется запариться, то скачайте мой первоисточник проблемы - весь  [репозиторий с гитхаба](https://github.com/VostokSisters/vostoksisters.github.io), установите node.js, gulp-cli и введите `npm i` (чтобы установить все пакеты и зависимости) в консоли в корне разархивированной папки с репозитория, а чтобы полностью скомпилировать весь сайт, можете ввести `gulp hard`, ну или чтобы проверить конкретно jekyll, то `gulp jekyll-build` ввести также в консоли.
Проверку проводить, конечно же, на 32-х битной системе Windows (у меня десятка, но мне кажется, это не имеет значения).

Comment: `jekyll.bat` где взять этот батник? у меня на него ругается

Comment: @Konstantin, а я без понятия. Я его в папке нод модулс не нашел по поиску даже...

Comment: просто у Вас идёт условие в гилпфайле если win32 тогда  `var pl = process.platform === "win32" ? "jekyll.bat" : "jekyll";` вызывается батник

Comment: попробуйте заменить  `child.exec(pl, ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'}).on('close', done);` на  `child.exec("jekyll.bat", ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'}).on('close', done);`

Comment: тоесть явно указать child.exec(*"jekyll.bat"*...

Comment: @Konstantin, я указывал явно. Ошибка остается. То есть условие срабатывает правильно, в переменной находится строка "jekyll.bat".

Comment: и jekyll и jekyll.bat подставляли правильно? и не срабатывает?

Comment: у меня с *jekyll* таск выполняется

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, ну да, я пробовал запускать через `child.exec("jekyll", ['build'], {stdio: 'inherit'}).on('close', done);`, всё равно не запускается. Одинаковая ошибка в обоих случаях, указывая .bat и не указывая его...

Comment: [похожая ошибка](https://github.com/shakyShane/jekyll-gulp-sass-browser-sync/issues/2)

Comment: Так тут предлагают исключить из _config.yml node_modules

Comment: и ещё okonet вывел похожую ошибку. Рекомендует сделать `return child.spawn('bundle', ['exec', 'jekyll', 'build'], {stdio: 'inherit'})`

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, кстати, может прокатить, если установить бандл глобально. Этого я не делал и не пробовал ещё. А из конфига node_modules я первым делом исключил, не в этом проблема.